# Django many to one relationship, foreign key as text input

Tags: django, django-views

I have 2 databases, Book and Comment (one book could have many comments, but each comment only refers to one book). Each database has an HTML form for the user to input book data or comment. ISBN is the primary key for the Book database and foreign key for the Comment database. In both html form, user will use text input to input ISBN. How can I revise my html form and code below so that such many to one relationship will be created?

models.py

```
class Book(models.Model):
    ISBN = models.BigIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    Chinese_Book_Name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    English_Book_Name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank = True)
    Author_Name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Comment(models.Model):
    ISBN = models.ForeignKey(Book, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    age = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    score = models.IntegerField()
    comment = models.TextField()
    topic = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank = True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    contact = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank = True)
```

Views.py

```
def saveBook(request):
    ISBN = request.POST['ISBN']
    Chinese_Book_Name = request.POST['chinese name']
    English_Book_Name = request.POST['english name']
    Author_Name = request.POST['author name']

    book = Book(ISBN = ISBN, Chinese_Book_Name = Chinese_Book_Name, English_Book_Name = English_Book_Name, Author_Name = Author_Name)
    book.save()
    return redirect('/input/addComment')

def saveComment(request):
    ISBN = request.POST['ISBN']
    age = request.POST['age']
    score = request.POST['score']
    topic = request.POST['topic']
    name = request.POST['name']
    contact = request.POST['contact']

    comment = Comment(ISBN=ISBN, age = age, score = score, topic = topic, name = name, contact = contact)
    comment.save()
    return redirect('/')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have specified in your models, the `ISBN` field should refer to a `Book` object, not an string; Use this:

```
def saveComment(request):
        ISBN = request.POST['ISBN']
        age = request.POST['age']
        score = request.POST['score']
        topic = request.POST['topic']
        name = request.POST['name']
        contact = request.POST['contact']

        book = Book.objects.get(ISBN=ISBN)

        comment = Comment(ISBN=book, age = age, score = score, topic = topic, name = name, contact = contact)
        comment.save()
        return redirect('/')
```

Also keep in mind that as Django suggests, you should name your *Foreign keys* after your model's name; So in this case, you'd better change the `ISBN` field name (of `Comment` model) to `book`.

Comment: Thanks, but when I try to migrate, I still got error: django.db.utils.OperationalError: foreign key mismatch - "input_comment" referencing "input_book". Any thoughts?

Comment: When this error occurs? After changing the name of foreign key field (`ISBN` to `book`)? Please also include the full traceback of the error.

Comment: The full trackback is too long, but I think below is where error occors: Running migrations:
  Applying input.0024_auto_20191119_0048...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Julie Zhang\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 82, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql)
  File "C:\Users\Julie Zhang\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 381, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query)
sqlite3.OperationalError: foreign key mismatch - "input_comment" referencing "input_book"

Comment: Try removing _all_ migration files inside the migration directory, except the `__init__.py`; then run `make migration` and `migrate` again and see if that solves the problem.

Comment: I tried, the error is still there. Should I move __pycache__ as well?